# SVN, Apache, Win7 x64 - where to find mod_dav_svn and mod_dav_auth?

Tags: windows, apache, svn, module, 64-bit

I'm trying to get SVN + Apache going on Windows 7 x64 but apparently I need 64-bit versions of `mod_dav_svn.so` and `mod_dav_auth.so`.

Are these available somewhere?  I'm very much trying to avoid building them myself.

Spec:

- SlikSVN x64
- SVN 1.7.4
- Apache 2.2

---

*Some background*

The reason I say "apparently I need these" is from this log error:

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 492 of foo/httpd.conf: Cannot load
>   foo/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: The specified module could not
>   be found.

If I use a SVN binary for an x86 architecture, the error is the same, but the last sentence reads

> The specified procedure could not be found

which indicates an architecture problem, I think.  Can someone help out?

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=windows+mod_dav_svn.so ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, actually these modules were not the cause of the problem. As detailed [here](http://old.nabble.com/mod_dav_svn-integration-td14931619.html), the message is misleading and there are actually dependencies missing from those two files.

Over the last 24 hours, I read somewhere that after Subversion 1.5, the program uses DLLs.  Unfortunately, most of the directions out there are not yet updated to reflect this, so here's what I did, just for the next guy.

- Download and install a x64 Apache build from [ApacheHaus](http://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx)
- Download a Subversion mod build from the same place
- Grab mod_dav_svn and mod_dav_auth from `/modules` in the Subversion mod, put into `/modules` in the Apache
- Grab all the DLLs from Haus mod `/bin` and put into the Apache `/bin`
- (Re)start and cross fingers.

Apparently, to help with this sort of problem, [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is a good tool.

On to the next challenge!

Comment: what you mean by subversion mod build from the same place ?, I cannot find any SVN there in apachehaus

Comment: @rinilnath This was more than ten years ago so it's unlikely they're still in the same place :) ...and it's been about that long since I last used SVN, so I'm afraid I can't be of much help here anymore.

Comment: Right ok, it would be really great if you share any guide for setting up SVN server locally

Answer (score -2):

Install x64 Subversion server: 
CollabNet Subversion Edge 2.3.0 (for Windows 64 bit) or WANDisco UberSVN. Is it too hard to find?

Comment: This is not always an option as the installations may - and do - interfere with other installations, e.g. Trac.